modify global variable in a decorated function
I have a decorator which inits a global dict which I want to modify within the decorated function. I have tried an implementation something like below:
def decorator():
    def inner_function(func):
        global_dict = {}
        print("Inner function")
        ret = func()
        return ret
    return inner_function
    
@decorator()
def test_function():
    global global_dict
    global_dict["something"] = "something"
    print("Test function")
    return True

This gives me an error: name 'global_dict' is not defined and I am not really sure why. How would I go about doing this?

"I have a decorator which inits a global dict." No, you don't. Inside inner_function, global_dict is a local variable. You need a global statement, just like you have in test_function.

You have global global_dict in the wrong function. It should be in the function that assigns the variable, not the one that uses it.

the global_dict you initialise is local to inner_function

There's nothing special about decorators regarding global variables.

will this work if the decorated function is in another module ?
